# check-expect function

Tags: scheme, racket

```
;; snoc : X [Listof Any] -> [Listof Any]
;; Adds the X to the end of the list
(define (snoc x l)
  (cond [(empty? l) (cons x empty)]
        [else (cons (first l)
                    (snoc x (rest l)))]))
```

As described above, it simply adds an X to the end of the list. How would you write a simple check-expect function for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd test the obvious cases, for example:

1. What happens if we add an element to an empty list?
2. What happens if we add an element to a list with one element?
3. What happens if we add an element to a list with two elements?

And so on. For example, the first test would look like this:

```
(check-expect (snoc 1 '()) '(1))
```